# Custom TextField Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, jss

How do I customize the `TextField` especially the class below? in React Material UI?

```
  root: {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-inputMarginDense': {
      paddingBottom: 'none !important',
    },
  },


 <TextField className={classes.root} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space after the ampersand:

```
  root: {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-inputMarginDense': {
      paddingBottom: 'none !important',
    },
  },
```

`.MuiOutlinedInput-inputMarginDense` is a child class of `MuiTextField-root`

Comment: Yeah did it also. same thing

Comment: OK.  Maybe post a bit more code then to add context.  For example, are you using a global theme override?  Can you show how that is being added to your theme?  Are any other overrides working for you?